# How to write hello world without using header file in c

Tags: c, header-files, forward-declaration

How to write hello world without using header files in C?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

printf("Hello World");
getch();

}
```

This is simple C program with header file...

- `conio.h` - for console
- `stdio.h` - is used for `printf` and `scanf`

Comment: Simple, provide the forward declarations manually.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I think `main(){puts("Hello world");}` will compile successfully on most systems (albeit with a few warnings).

Comment: `main` returns an _integer_, so the declaration must be `int main()`.

Comment: @ForceBru With `main()`, the C spec specially allows " or in some other implementation-deﬁned manner" 5.1.2.2.1 1 which could include `void main()` on OP's platform.  Yet returning `int` is best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need header files primarily because of the prototype declaration of library functions plus any necessary types and additional macros
needed to facilitate their use. They are provided in form of header files for ease of re-use.

In your case, you can write the prototypes on your own and you should be okay Something like

```
/*  Prototypes on your own */
int getchar(void);
int printf(const char *format, ...);
int puts(const char *s);

int main(void) {  //this is the prescribed signature for hosted environment
    //printf("Hello World\n");    //not good to use printf if don;t need conversion
    puts("Hello World");
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

should do just fine.

Comment: Writing your own forward declarations of standard C functions is a bad idea. Some functions are implemented as macros, and some library functions might have extra pragmas (For example `printf` functions might have special pragma to enable type checking for format string arguments).

Comment: @user694733 it still works, though. The standard requires that a non-macro version be available for all standard functions

Comment: @user694733 and that's why the headers are there, to save from all the trouble. Please note, I wrote _"just fine"_, not _"the same"_ :)